# getting different hashes from crypto.createHash()

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape some data using puppeteer and look if that data was updated, so i thought i could store hash of that data and look if it was different every day but when i hash it it with crypto.createHash(), it gives back different hash every time even though data is still same.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const crypto = require("crypto");

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/rmji")
    await page.waitForSelector("#accordion li.chapter-item a")
    const chapters = await page.$$eval('#accordion li.chapter-item a', anchors => {
        return anchors.map(anchor => anchor.textContent)
    })
    const hashed = crypto.createHash("md5").update(chapters.toString()).digest("hex");
    console.log(hashed)
    await browser.close()
})()
```

UPDATE:
After some testing i think i narrowed down what can cause this -
by adding .slice to our results i found out that having 1 or 2 results works fine, but adding third result somehow always breaks it. So error is somewhere inside page.$$eval function

```
return anchors.map(anchor => anchor.textContent).slice(0, 2)
```

It is also weird that if i try to use .getAttribute('href') instead of .textContent or .innerHtml everything works fine.

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto ? Looks like the package is deprecated. Did you try any other alternatives?

Comment: @DaniVijay No, i was using built-in [crypto nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), i tried using [sha-1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1) but got same result, meaning that i'm somehow getting additional data with `page.$$eval`,